# How to change or remove asp RadioButton GroupName in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to change or remove asp `RadioButton` GroupName in Javascript.

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="optbtnRight" Text="Right" GroupName="second"/>

I have this function.

function ddlColumnType_onchange(){

    document.getElementById("<%=optbtnRight.ClientID %>").checked = false;
    //Want set group here        
}
```

I have call this on

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColumnType" runat="server" class="text small" 
     onchange="ddlColumnType_onchange()">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Why? It would only set itself after a postback?

Comment: What event will fire to trigger the change or removal?

Comment: I want to change the name on drop down on change event. and want to set it using JavaScript.

Comment: I don't want to do post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would suggest you to use html radio button with runat="server" rather than asp radio button to let same javascript work in all the browsers without any issue as asp radio button gets rendered differently in different browsers
So the first thing would be

Replace this

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="optbtnRight" Text="Right" GroupName="second"/>
```

With this

```
<input type="radio" runat="server" ID="optbtnRight" value="Right" name="second"/> Right
```

Then this should work for you

jQuery

```
$('#<%=optbtnRight.ClientID%>').attr("name","NewGroupName");
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('<%=optbtnRight.ClientID%>').setAttribute("name","NewGroupName");
```